# Which of two quantities is greater?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

Let $x$ and $y$ be two positive real numbers such that $x>y$. Which of the quantities is bigger and when?

1. $(x-y)\log\left(1-\frac{y}{x}\right)$
2. $x\log\left(1-\frac{y}{x+y}\right)$

Comment: $\log(1-\frac y{x+y})=\log\frac x{x+y}=\log x-\log (x+y)$ and with some similar work, the other one looks quite similar; these appear to be designed with some degree of symmetry in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(x-y) \log \left(1-\frac{y}{x}\right) = (x-y) \log \left(\frac{x-y}{x}\right) = \log \left(\left(\frac{x-y}{x}\right)^{x-y}\right)$$

$$x \log\left(1-\frac{y}{x+y}\right) = x \log\left(\frac{x}{x+y}\right) = \log\left(\left(\frac{x}{x+y}\right)^{x}\right)$$

Now, since log is strictly increasing, we might as well compare $(\frac{x}{x+y})^{x}$ and $(\frac{x-y}{x})^{x-y}$.

Now, multiply both by $(x+y)^x x^{x-y}$, so then we are comparing $x^{2x-y}$ and $(x-y)^{x-y}(x+y)^x$.

Comment: Hi. I have a follow-up question: I need to show $(x-y)^{((x-y)/(2x-y))}\times (x+y)^{((x)/(2x-y))}>x$. I am not sure how the AM-GM inequality leads to this, as the GM is on the LHS?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure anymore.

Comment: You can write it as a single variable $z=y/x$

Comment: @Michael Can you clarify?

Comment: From the start, divide by $x$.  Then you compare $(1-z)\log(1-z)$ and $-\log(1+z)$

Comment: Thanks @Michael. For the comparison of these functions, (say $f$ and $g$), I can simply show $f(0)=g(0)$, the slope of $g$ is more negative than that of $f$ and that $g$ is decreasing throughout $(0,1)$. Is that right or is there a more compact way of doing this?